# "Error: Could not find or load main class" JavaFX Terminal

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, terminal, javafx-8

I'm using the following class from my JavaFX Tutorial:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloFXApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Launch the JavaFX application
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Hello JavaFX Application");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu and I have the correct path to my .java file in my Terminal..
When I type "javac HelloFXApp.java" it works fine and a new "HelloFXApp.class" file is created. but when I try "java HelloFXApp" I receive the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class HelloFXApp

I checked my Java version by typing "java -version" and it looks like I have the latest one:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Please tell me if I missed something! 
Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `the package` while firing `java` command. (Implied from the comments, since it is not included in the question)

After compiling, navigate back to `src folder` and append the package to your class name :

```
java com.jdojo.intro.HelloFXApp
```